# Calculating fair value of an oanda.com box option

Tags: options, calculation, black-scholes

How do I calculate the theoretical "fair value" of an oanda.com box option?

More specifically, how do I calculate the probability that a given
FOREX parity will enter a given range in a given period of time.

Example: probability that USDCAD will trade between 1.0200 and 1.0250
sometime between noon GMT this Monday afternoon and 7pm GMT this
Monday afternoon?

Calculating the probability that USDCAD will be between 1.0200 and
1.0250 *at* noon (hitting the left edge of the box) is a fairly easy
Black-Scholes computation, assuming you have a good source for
time/price based volatility.

It's also easy (or at least possible) to calculate the probability
that USDCAD will be outside that range at noon, but *in* that range at
7pm (missing the left edge of the box, but hitting the right
edge). This requires integrating for all prices outside 1.0200-1.0250
and is ugly, but not uncomputable.

The problem: if USDCAD is at 1.0190 at noon, rises to 1.0210 at 3pm,
and sinks back to 1.0190 at 7pm, that still counts as a hit, but
neither case above will catch it.

I've played around with binary/ternary methods (which also require
knowing how frequently the market trades), but am wondering if there's
a simpler approach I'm overlooking.

If anyone's deeply interested, oanda.com offers free trial accounts,
and provides instantaneous pricing on most box options (which means
there's definitely a server-side formula for them-- it's not
hand-computed each time). I've requested their formula, but am not
sure how they'll respond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9608/determining-distribution-of-maximum-of-dependent-normal-variables/9740#9740 I've now created a Mathematica script that does this:

https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/box-option-value.m